# How delete "?" from url with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

at first url was like this:

> site.com/fr/index.php?category/ololo

after .htaccess rules it looks like:

> site.com/fr/?category/ololo

How Can I delete "?" symbol before category?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# URL Rewriting DotClear 2
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fr/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /dotclear/ /fr/
Redirect 301 /dotclear/public/ /dtc/public

# mod_rewrite


RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\index.php?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,PT,L]


# Generic

#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -Indexes
#php_value register_globals 0
```

Comment: Is `/fr/` a real directory? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: yes, there is /fr/ and /en/ directory. CMS structure

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located and what CMS are you using?

Comment: @СергейИлларионов This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969396/ridirecting-to-a-site-when-there-is-a-question-mark-in-the-url/24969505#24969505

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the "?"

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\index.php\?$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

I haven't use apache in a while but that might do it...

Comment: After it I have got url like this site.com/fr/index.php?category/aquarelles

Comment: Try changing a bit the expression. Match every URL and add the index.php? in the second parameter to RewriteRule. Something like `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /index.php? [QSA]`
if you want to remove the index.php? from every URL.