# Ridirecting to a site when there is a ?(question mark) in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need an htaccess which redirects if there is a ?(question mark) in the URL,

Some sample URL's,

```
mysite.com/?p=44
mysite.com/?m=44
mysite.com/?cat=44
mysite.com/index.php?cat=44
```

The question mark could be anywhere after the "/". It should work for with the "www" and without it as well.

If there is a question mark, it should go to newsite.com.

Since I'm new to htaccess I don't know how to go about it and new some help from you'll.
Thanks.

Comment: This could be done with PHP's `GET`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

If you are using Apache v2.4 you can use [`QSD`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag instead of `?` in your `RewriteRule` target URI

```
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com [L,R=301,QSD]
```

**Description:**

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` is special variable which contains query string part of the URI (e.g: `var=123`) And it doesn't contain `?` because it already knows if `?` is in the URI, it is part of query string `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

The `^(.+)$` is regex which says the query string in the URI must start `^` and end `$` with containing any character `.` one or more time `+` within the `()` capturing group.

So this basically means if any query string appended to your URI the condition `RewriteCond` becomes truthy and the next line `RewriteRule` do its work to redirect to your new URL.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you @RahilWazir and anubhava. I'm now off to google to figure out what those lines mean.

Comment: This one, 'RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$' @RahilWazir. I was thinking the "?" would be in that line since we are looking to check if the URL has "?" in it. What does (.+) mean ?