# mod_rewrite GET parameters to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters, clean-urls

I need to rewrite url

```
http://domain.com/dir/aaa?param_1=XXX&param_2=YYY
```

to

```
http://domain.com/YYY/aaa/XXX
```

can't get it to work...

EDIT:

this is the code I used:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param_1=(.*)&param_2=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/$2/aaa/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: _can't get it to work_? Then show your code

Comment: I edited my post and showed the code.

Comment: You need to replace `$1` and `$2` to `%1` and `%2`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now it rewrites the URL as I wanted, but it still keeps the original parameters at the end of the new URL. (http://domain.com/YYY/aaa/XXX?param_1=XXX&param_2=YYY). Can you please advise how to get rid of them?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24969505/2706988. Or put `?` at end of the target url like so `/aaa/$1?`